# Complexity of a pattern algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have been trying to find an algorith to determine the complexity of a pattern with this coordinate system on the left and the possible lines on the right handside of the picture:

[image]

I am trying to find an algorith to determine the complexity of a pattern with this coordinate system on the left and the possible lines on the right handside of the picture: enter image description here

The rules for building the pattern are the following:

- Only the lines depicted can be used
- A line cannot stand alone which means it must be connected to at least another line.
- When you devide the pattern into four segments (top left, top right, bottom left and bottom right) there must be at least two segments covered with lines which results in a minimum number of lines of two.

Well, so far to the definition of a pattern which is not the actual problem. The problem is that I want to have three difficulty levels of patterns (easy, medium and hard). On the following some examples of different patterns with different difficulty levels:

[image]

I have been trying to find a rule with inner lines (lines that spread out from the center) and outer lines (lines on the edge) but I cannot come up with a good algorithm to determine the complexity of a pattern. For me the number of lines is surely one of the possibilities but I am not really happy with that alone because the distinction between easy and medium with this rule would not be given as seen on the picture. I don't even know whether it can be solved with an algorith, should I better hardcode it? I am little bit clueless about this problem and any help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You're doing it the wrong way around. First figure out what makes a pattern "easy", "medium" or "heavy", **then** come up with an algorithm. It's absolutely unclear what makes a pattern comply to either complexity. If I had to guess I'd say it's a mixture of symmetry and number of lines, but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put that here for the moment, not completed, I'll try to continue working on it but that Python source code can help :

```
link_masks = [
  0xB0000, 0xCE000, 0x41800,
  0x28580, 0x15670, 0x02A0C,
  0x00142, 0x000AB, 0x00015
]

easy_patterns = [0xE0C25, 0xC1043, 0xE4F27, 0xF1957]
medium_patterns = [0xD0C67, 0x95E30, 0x95622, 0xC5463]
hard_patterns = [0xE5975, 0xB5E75, 0xF4C75, 0xF5D75]
patterns = [("easy", easy_patterns), ("medium", medium_patterns), ("hard", hard_patterns)]

def getPatternInfos(pattern):
  bs = [True if n == "1" else False for n in str(bin(pattern))[2::]]
  links = {}
  for link in range(len(link_masks)):
    bitwiseLink = str(bin(int(bin(link_masks[link])[2::], 2) & int(bin(pattern)[2::], 2)))[2::]
    links[link] = [True if n == "1" else False for n in bitwiseLink].count(True)
  lines = bs.count(True)
  return bs, links, lines

def checkPatternComplexity(pattern):
  bs, links, lines = getPatternInfos(pattern)
  linksAmount = sum(links.values())
  print("<Pattern>")
  print("Number of lines :", lines)
  printCube(bs)
  print(links)
  print(linksAmount, "links")
  print("Max links :", max(links.values()))
  print("</Pattern>")

def printIfTrue(condition, text = "■ "):
  if condition:
    print(text, end="")
  else:
    print(" "*len(text), end="")

def orOnList(cube, indexes):
  return (sum([cube[i] for i in indexes]) > 0)

def printCube(cube):
  for y in range(9):
    if y == 0: printIfTrue(orOnList(cube, [0, 2, 3]))
    if y == 4: printIfTrue(orOnList(cube, [2, 4, 9, 11, 12]))
    if y == 8: printIfTrue(orOnList(cube, [11, 13, 18]))
    if y in [0, 4, 8]:
      printIfTrue(cube[int((y / 4) + (y * 2))], "■ ■ ■ ")
      if y == 0: printIfTrue(orOnList(cube, [0, 1, 4, 5, 6]))
      if y == 4: printIfTrue(orOnList(cube, [3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15]))
      if y == 8: printIfTrue(orOnList(cube, [12, 14, 16, 18, 19]))
      printIfTrue(cube[int((y / 4) + (y * 2)) + 1], "■ ■ ■ ")
    elif y in [1, 5]:
      for i in range(7):
        if i in [2, 5]:
          print(" ", end=" ")
        printIfTrue(cube[y * 2 + (1 - (y % 5)) + i])
    elif y in [2, 6]:
      for i in range(5):
        if i in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
          print(" ", end=" ")
        if i in [1, 3]:
          if i == 1 and y == 2:
            printIfTrue(orOnList(cube, [3, 4]))
          elif i == 3 and y == 2:
            printIfTrue(orOnList(cube, [6, 7]))
          if i == 1 and y == 6:
            printIfTrue(orOnList(cube, [12, 13]))
          elif i == 3 and y == 6:
            printIfTrue(orOnList(cube, [15, 16]))
        else:
          printIfTrue(cube[(y * 2 - (1 if y == 6 else 2)) + i + int(i / 4 * 2)])
    elif y in [3, 7]:
      for i in range(7):
        if i in [2, 5]:
          print("  ", end="")
        ri, swap = (y * 2 - 2) + (1 - (y % 5)) + i, [[3, 6, 12, 15], [4, 7, 13, 16]]
        if ri in swap[0]: ri = swap[1][swap[0].index(ri)]
        elif ri in swap[1]: ri = swap[0][swap[1].index(ri)]
        printIfTrue(cube[ri])
    if y == 0: printIfTrue(orOnList(cube, [1, 7, 8]))
    if y == 4: printIfTrue(orOnList(cube, [6, 8, 10, 16, 17]))
    if y == 8: printIfTrue(orOnList(cube, [15, 17, 19]))
    print()

for pattern_group in patterns:
  print("Current Real Complexity :", pattern_group[0])
  for pattern in pattern_group[1]:
    checkPatternComplexity(pattern)
```

Here is the produced output (You can test it on http://repl.it for example) :

```
Current Real Complexity : easy
<Pattern>
Number of lines : 8
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
■               ■ 
■               ■ 
■               ■ 
■ ■ ■ ■ ■       ■ 
        ■       ■ 
        ■       ■ 
        ■       ■ 
        ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
{0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 0, 7: 2, 8: 2}
16 links
Max links : 2
</Pattern>
<Pattern>
Number of lines : 6
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
              ■   
            ■     
          ■       
        ■         
      ■           
    ■             
  ■               
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 0, 4: 2, 5: 0, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 1}
12 links
Max links : 2
</Pattern>
<Pattern>
Number of lines : 12
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
■       ■       ■ 
■       ■       ■ 
■       ■       ■ 
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
■       ■       ■ 
■       ■       ■ 
■       ■       ■ 
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
{0: 2, 1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 3, 6: 2, 7: 3, 8: 2}
24 links
Max links : 4
</Pattern>
<Pattern>
Number of lines : 12
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
■ ■           ■ ■ 
■   ■       ■   ■ 
■     ■   ■     ■ 
■       ■       ■ 
■     ■   ■     ■ 
■   ■       ■   ■ 
■ ■           ■ ■ 
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
{0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 4, 5: 2, 6: 3, 7: 2, 8: 3}
24 links
Max links : 4
</Pattern>
Current Real Complexity : medium
<Pattern>
Number of lines : 10
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
  ■             ■ 
    ■           ■ 
      ■         ■ 
■ ■ ■ ■ ■       ■ 
      ■ ■       ■ 
    ■   ■       ■ 
  ■     ■       ■ 
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
{0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 4, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 3, 8: 2}
20 links
Max links : 4
</Pattern>
<Pattern>
Number of lines : 9
■ ■ ■ ■ ■       ■ 
  ■     ■     ■ ■ 
    ■   ■   ■   ■ 
      ■ ■ ■     ■ 
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
        ■ ■       
        ■   ■     
        ■     ■   
        ■       ■ 
{0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 7, 5: 2, 6: 0, 7: 1, 8: 1}
18 links
Max links : 7
</Pattern>
<Pattern>
Number of lines : 8
■ ■ ■ ■ ■       ■ 
  ■     ■     ■   
    ■   ■   ■     
      ■ ■ ■       
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
        ■         
        ■         
        ■         
■ ■ ■ ■ ■         
{0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 6, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 2, 8: 0}
16 links
Max links : 6
</Pattern>
<Pattern>
Number of lines : 9
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
        ■     ■   
        ■   ■     
        ■ ■       
■ ■ ■ ■ ■         
      ■ ■         
    ■   ■         
  ■     ■         
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
{0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 5, 5: 0, 6: 2, 7: 3, 8: 1}
18 links
Max links : 5
</Pattern>
Current Real Complexity : hard
<Pattern>
Number of lines : 12
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
■       ■     ■ ■ 
■       ■   ■   ■ 
■       ■ ■     ■ 
■       ■       ■ 
■     ■ ■ ■     ■ 
■   ■   ■   ■   ■ 
■ ■     ■     ■ ■ 
■       ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
{0: 2, 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 5, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 3}
24 links
Max links : 5
</Pattern>
<Pattern>
Number of lines : 13
■ ■ ■ ■ ■       ■ 
■ ■     ■     ■ ■ 
■   ■   ■   ■   ■ 
■     ■ ■ ■     ■ 
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
      ■ ■ ■     ■ 
    ■   ■   ■   ■ 
  ■     ■     ■ ■ 
■       ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
{0: 3, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 8, 5: 3, 6: 1, 7: 2, 8: 3}
26 links
Max links : 8
</Pattern>
<Pattern>
Number of lines : 12
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
■ ■     ■       ■ 
■   ■   ■       ■ 
■     ■ ■       ■ 
■ ■ ■ ■ ■       ■ 
      ■ ■ ■     ■ 
    ■   ■   ■   ■ 
  ■     ■     ■ ■ 
■       ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
{0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 6, 5: 2, 6: 1, 7: 2, 8: 3}
24 links
Max links : 6
</Pattern>
<Pattern>
Number of lines : 14
■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
■ ■     ■     ■ ■ 
■   ■   ■   ■   ■ 
■     ■ ■ ■     ■ 
■ ■ ■ ■ ■       ■ 
■     ■ ■ ■     ■ 
■   ■   ■   ■   ■ 
■ ■     ■     ■ ■ 
■       ■ ■ ■ ■ ■ 
{0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 7, 5: 2, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 3}
28 links
Max links : 7
</Pattern>
```

`links_masks` contains the possible links for each points.

You can edit the `checkPatternComplexity` function to evaluate the complexity of the current pattern, you have access to the amount of lines, the amount of liasons for each point and all the liaisons (encoded in bits).

Here are the bitmasks for every liaisons :

```
X : 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20


1 : 1  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2 : 1  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3 : 0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4 : 0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5 : 0  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0
6 : 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0
7 : 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0
8 : 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   1
9 : 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1
```

I also put here the 12 first shapes encoded :

```
X :  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20

1 :  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1
2 :  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1
3 :  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  1   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   1
4 :  1  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   1
5 :  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  1   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1
6 :  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   0
7 :  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0
8 :  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  0   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   1
9 :  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  1  1   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   1
10 : 1  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  1   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   1
11 : 1  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   1
12 : 1  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  1   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   1
```

And here is how I encoded the points / links :
[image]

If the link exists, it's 1, else it's 0.

Comment: Wow thank you so much for your answer. I have to get to know Python first a little better to understand your code as I am used to Java. But I surely will test it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas on the criterias you can use for the complexity of a pattern:

1. The number of lines
2. The maximum of the number of lines connected to a single point
3. The number of diagonals lines used
4. The number of "subparts" (number of triangles, squares etc., however its a little hard to code)
5. The number of points covered by at least one line

At least that's what I came up with looking at your examples. (Shocking differences between the hard & easy patterns)